# Entity Framework - is excessive use of "EntityState.Unchanged" really needed?

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, datatables, record

Thanks for taking your time!

I'm currently prototyping a smartphone webstore as a part of learning Entity Framework, I stumbled on a problem where new records in my database would add additional records in related tables. I managed to work around this problem by following this post [Prevent Adding New Record on Related Table Entity in Entity Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48816929/prevent-adding-new-record-on-related-table-entity-in-entity-framework).

However, it seems quite tedious to add `EntityState.Unchanged` for each and every entity whenever I want to add a record, so I'm starting to think I might have made an error.

Please take at the following code that is used for check out:

```
    public ActionResult CheckOut()
    {
        // Save cart
        Order order = new Order() { Payed = false, Canceled = false };
        db.Orders.Add(order);

        for (int i = 0; i < cartItems.Count; i++)
        {
            cartItems[i].Order = order;
            cartItems[i].OrderId = order.OrderId;

            db.CartItems.Add(cartItems[i]);

            db.Entry(cartItems[i].Item).State = EntityState.Unchanged;
            db.Entry(cartItems[i].Item.Memory).State = EntityState.Unchanged;
            db.Entry(cartItems[i].Item.ScreenSize).State = EntityState.Unchanged;
            db.Entry(cartItems[i].Item.OperatingSystem).State = EntityState.Unchanged;
        }

        db.SaveChanges();
        cartItems.Clear();

        return View();
    }
```

The method takes whatever items the user has put into the cart and adds them into the database. If I don't set `State` to `EntityState.Unchanged`, the referenced entities will be added as new records into their corresponding tables.

For better understanding, here's the `Item` entity and the `CartItem` class:

```
public class Item
{
    public int ItemId { get; set; }
    public int MemoryId { get; set; }
    public int OperatingSystemId { get; set; }
    public int BrandId { get; set; }
    public int ScreenSizeId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public float Price { get; set; }

    public Memory Memory { get; set; }
    public OperatingSystem OperatingSystem { get; set; }
    public ScreenSize ScreenSize { get; set; }
}

public class CartItem
{
    public int CartItemId { get; set; }
    public int OrderId { get; set; }
    public int ItemId { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }

    public Order Order { get; set; }
    public Item Item{ get; set; }
}
```

What really grinds my gears is that if I combine the code that is used to add items into the cart and the checkout-method, I don't get this problem at all *(notice the lack of `state = EntityState.Unchanged`)*.

```
    public ActionResult ProblemFreeCheckOut()
    {
        // Add Items to cart...
        var item1= db.Items.Include(i => i.Memory).Include(i => i.OperatingSystem).Include(i => i.ScreenSize).Where(i => i.ItemId == 1);
        var item2= db.Items.Include(i => i.Memory).Include(i => i.OperatingSystem).Include(i => i.ScreenSize).Where(i => i.ItemId== 2);

        CartItems List<CartItems> = new List<CartItem>();

        cartItems.Add(new CartItem { Quantity = 1, ItemId = item1.First().ItemId, Item = item1.First() });
        cartItems.Add(new CartItem { Quantity = 1, ItemId= item2.First().ItemId, Item = item2.First() });

        // Save cart
        Order order = new Order() { Payed = false, Canceled = false };
        db.Orders.Add(order);

        for (int i = 0; i < cartItems.Count; i++)
        {
            cartItems[i].Order = order;
            cartItems[i].OrderId = order.OrderId;
            db.CartItems.Add(cartItems[i]);
        }

        db.SaveChanges();
        cartItems.Clear();

        return View();
    }
```

To summarize and clarify what I'm trying to do: I want to be able to split the code above into two parts: one `Add` method and one `Checkout` method. The `Add` method will add items from database into the a list of items that will later be utilized by the `Checkout` method. I have got this working, by an excessive use of `EntityState.Unchanged` - is this really needed?

Thanks a lot if you got this far in the post, I salute you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at the documentation for the Add<TEntity>(TEntity) method:

> Begins tracking the given entity, and any other reachable entities
>   that are not already being tracked, in the Added state such that they
>   will be inserted into the database when SaveChanges() is called.

So what happens is, by calling the `Add` method you tell the EF: "treat everything I just attached to the context (via the relation graph) as a new item".
In the second example you don't encounter the problem because the related entities are already being tracked when you `Include` them. In that case EF simply keeps the `Unchanged` stated which results in them being ignored during `SaveChanges()`.

Purely from the technical point of view, you have two options. Either:
1) do what you do in your second example - track the related entities before calling the `Add()` method so that EF knows to treat them as `Unchanged`.
or
2) instead of adding the entity graph outright

```
db.CartItems.Add(cartItem);
```

just attach it (all the entities will be tracked as `Unchanged` by default) and then mark your `cartItem` as added:

```
db.CartItems.Attach(cartItem).State = EntityState.Added;
```

On that last point - it might even be that just `db.CartItems.Attach(cartItem);` is enough as EF sets state to `Added` for entities that don't have their primary key fields set. My memory is a bit fuzzy on that one. In any case this is a good place to put a breakpoint and debug to see how EF does it's tracking magic. There is a great blog post on this subject, which I recommend:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2013/april/data-points-why-does-entity-framework-reinsert-existing-objects-into-my-database

Comment: Thanks a lot!
It seems I didn't quite understand how the DBContext worked and your post nudged me in the right direction. This article from Microsoft was very helpful: [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/saving/change-tracking/entity-state) .